# How do I execute a method only after another finish?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two method `saveLesson()` and `uploadFile()` which takes some time to finish.

I'd like for the second method must start only after the first one finish.

```
saveLesson();
if (!lessonDetails.get("file").matches(";No file attached")) {
    ArrayList<String> allFileUris = getFileNames(lessonDetails.get("file"));
    uploadFile(allFileUris);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of both saveLesson() and uploadFile().

Comment: I improved your title and grammar, but you really need to [edit] to add more code for us to be able to help you. See: How to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can take below approaches for the same

1) you can call second method from first method itself in the last of first method.

2) You can create a Asynctask and execute first method and after the first method is executed  then onPostExecute method call another method

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to suit some needs

```
boolean firstFunctionResult = firstFunction("1");
```

**Second Function**

```
if (firstFunctionResult) {

    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                   "Dance",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Can Run Some Function Here

}
```

**First Function**

```
public boolean firstFunction(String variableToCheck) {

    if (variableToCheck=="1") {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

One is tempted to test a way with OnActivityResult - but one fears it will not be reusable..